# Inequality "A la Rozenberg"

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, contest-math

Hello I want to solve [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2131374/if-a3b3c3-3-so-fraca3ab-fracb3bc-fracc3ca-geq-frac)

The inequality is equivalent to this :

$$\frac{a^2}{b^2}cos(arctan(\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}))^2+\cos(\arctan(\sqrt{\frac{c}{b}}))^2+\frac{c^2}{b^2}\cos(\arctan(\sqrt{\frac{a}{c}}))^2\geq \frac{3}{2b^2}$$

We put :

$\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}=\frac{x+y}{1-xy}$

$\sqrt{\frac{c}{b}}=\frac{z+y}{1-yz}$

$\sqrt{\frac{a}{c}}=\frac{x+z}{1-xz}$

Where $x$,$y$,$z$ are positive real numbers with the condition

$1>xy$,$1>xz$,$1>zy$.

We get :

$$(\frac{1-xy}{x+y})^4\cos(\arctan(\frac{x+y}{1-xy}))^2+\cos(\arctan(\frac{z+y}{1-yz}))^2+(\frac{z+y}{1-yz})^4\cos(\arctan(\frac{x+z}{1-xz}))^2\geq \frac{3^{\frac{1}{3}}}{2}(1+(\frac{1-xy}{x+y})^6+(\frac{z+y}{1-yz})^6)^{\frac{2}{3}}$$

Wich is equivalent to :

$$(\frac{1-xy}{x+y})^4(\frac{1}{(\frac{x+y}{1-xy})^2+1})+\frac{1}{(\frac{z+y}{1-yz})^2+1}+(\frac{z+y}{1-yz})^4\frac{1}{(\frac{x+z}{1-xz})^2+1}\geq \frac{3^{\frac{1}{3}}}{2}(1+(\frac{1-xy}{x+y})^6+(\frac{z+y}{1-yz})^6)^{\frac{2}{3}}$$

And if we make a substitution like this  :

$A=\frac{1-xy}{x+y}$

$B=\frac{z+y}{1-yz}$

$C=\frac{x+z}{1-xz}$

We get :

$$A^4(\frac{1}{(\frac{1}{A})^2+1})+\frac{1}{(B)^2+1}+B^4\frac{1}{(C)^2+1}\geq \frac{3^{\frac{1}{3}}}{2}(1+(A)^6+(B)^6)^{\frac{2}{3}}$$

With the condition :

$(\frac{\frac{1}{A^6}+1+B^6}{3})^{-1}+(\frac{C^6+1+\frac{1}{B^6}}{3})^{-1}+(\frac{\frac{1}{C^6}+1+A^6}{3})^{-1}=3$

Wich is equivalent to :

$(\frac{3A^6}{A^6B^6+1+A^6})+(\frac{3B^6}{C^6B^6+1+B^6})+(\frac{3C^6}{A^6C^6+1+C^6})=3$

After that I can't continue.

Thanks.

Comment: is the cosine squared or its argument?

Comment: i think this inequality is from Mathlinks

Comment: Do we agree that usually out friend Rozenberg works on expressions that are cyclically invariant, which is not the case here ?

Comment: I simply don't understand your goal. I understand you want to prove an inequality that has already been proven in a different way by introducing trigonometry (btw, my personal opinion is that it is, right at the root, not the best idea because it complexifies things) ; you reach a deadend which an expression with no good properties: surely not simpler that the initial one and with a big drawback: you have lost the cyclically symmetry. Not worth the value to continue...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If $a^3+b^3+c^3=3$ so $\frac{a^3}{a+b}+\frac{b^3}{b+c}+\frac{c^3}{c+a}\geq\frac{3}{2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2131374/if-a3b3c3-3-so-fraca3ab-fracb3bc-fracc3ca-geq-frac)

Answer (score 0):

To start we study the following function :

$$f(x)=\frac{x^3}{x^2+1}+\frac{1}{h^2+1}+\frac{h}{y^2+1}-\frac{3^{\frac{2}{3}}}{2}(x^3+h^3+1)^{\frac{1}{3}}$$

The derivative of function is :

$$f'(x)=\frac{1}{2}x^2[\frac{-3^{\frac{2}{3}}}{(h^3+x^3+1)^{\frac{2}{3}}}-\frac{(4x^2)}{(x^2+1)^2}+\frac{6}{(x^2+1)}]$$

So we study this part of the derivative:

$$[\frac{-3^{\frac{2}{3}}}{(h^3+x^3+1)^{\frac{2}{3}}}-\frac{(4x^2)}{(x^2+1)^2}+\frac{6}{(x^2+1)}]$$

We remark this :

$$[\frac{-3^{\frac{2}{3}}}{(h^3+x^3+1)^{\frac{2}{3}}}-\frac{(4x^2)}{(x^2+1)^2}+\frac{6}{(x^2+1)}]\geq [\frac{-3^{\frac{2}{3}}}{(x^3+1)^{\frac{2}{3}}}-\frac{(4x^2)}{(x^2+1)^2}+\frac{6}{(x^2+1)}]>0$$

So the derivative is positive and the function is increasing :

So we have this :

$$f(x)\geq f(0)$$

Wich is equivalent to :

$$f(x)\geq \frac{1}{h^2+1}+\frac{h}{y^2+1}-\frac{3^{\frac{2}{3}}}{2}(h^3+1)^{\frac{1}{3}}$$

Now we combine this with the initial condition :

$$\frac{3h}{hy+1+y}+\frac{3y}{1+y}=3$$

We get :

$$\frac{1}{h^2+1}+\frac{h}{(h-1)^2+1}-\frac{3^{\frac{2}{3}}}{2}(h^3+1)^{\frac{1}{3}}\geq 0$$

Done!

Comment: You work with another problem.

Comment: Yes in fact there is a link between the initial problem and my problem .

Comment: See better please.

Comment: There is some mistakes surely . My ethics is given my ideas to others. I just hope that you will find cause in it.Sorry for the bad english I'm french .

Comment: Dear @FatsWallers My inequality it's $\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{a^3}{a+b}\geq\frac{3}{2}$, but you work with an inequality $\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{a^3}{a^2+b^2}\geq\frac{3}{2}$,

Comment: Wow sorry , I will correct this .

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg I correct and can you tell me if there are some mistakes in my question ?

Comment: You still work with another inequality. See my previous comment.