# A little refinement of an inequality

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, contest-math

Hello I have an inequality to prove [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2131374/if-a3b3c3-3-so-fraca3ab-fracb3bc-fracc3ca-geq-frac) :

Let $a,b,c$ real numbers with $1>a>-1,\;1>b>-1,\;1>c>-1$ with the condition :
$$\left(\frac{1+a}{1-a}\right)^3+\left(\frac{1+b}{1-b}\right)^3+\left(\frac{1+c}{1-c}\right)^3=3$$
So we have :
$$\frac{(|a|+1)^3}{2(1-|a|)|a|}\left(\frac{1}{1-|a|}-\frac{1}{1-|ab|}\right)+\frac{(|b|+1)^3}{2(1-|b|)|b|}\left(\frac{1}{1-|b|}-\frac{1}{1-|bc|}\right)+\frac{(|c|+1)^3}{2(1-|c|)|c|}\left(\frac{1}{1-|c|}-\frac{1}{1-|ac|}\right)\geq$$  $$\geq\frac{(|a|+1)^3}{2(1-|a|)|a|}\left(\frac{1}{1-|a|}-\frac{1}{1-a^2}\right)+\frac{(|b|+1)^3}{2(1-|b|)|b|}\left(\frac{1}{1-|b|}-\frac{1}{1-b^2}\right)+\frac{(|c|+1)^3}{2(1-|c|)|c|}\left(\frac{1}{1-|c|}-\frac{1}{1-c^2}\right)\geq$$  $$\geq\frac{3}{2}$$

Edit : If you want to know more see [this french website](http://www.les-mathematiques.net/phorum/read.php?4,1484510,page=1).More particulary the big message at the end where I use Karamata's inequality , rearrangement inequality , and other things.

Maybe the convexity could be usefull in your case.
Thanks a lot for your answer .

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Hello uniquesolution , yes in fact I forgot it .My question is how to prove this two inequality ?

Comment: What exactly is the relation between your question and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2131374/if-a3b3c3-3-so-fraca3ab-fracb3bc-fracc3ca-geq-frac? Are the inequalities following *"So we have"* what you already know, or what you want to prove?

Comment: I just use this substitution $$\frac{1+sin(x)}{1-sin(x)}$$ and put $a=sin(x)$ into the inequality .And it's what I want to prove .

Comment: I suggest you to update your question and tell what exactly  the questions is and if you have, your own opinions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The middle member of your inequality equals $h(|a|)+h(|b|)+h(|c|)$, where $h(t)=\frac{(t+1)^3}{2(1-t)t}\left(\frac 1{1-t}-\frac 1{1-t^2}\right)=\frac 12\left(\frac {1+t}{1-t}\right)^2$, when $t\ne 0$, and is undefined when $t=0$. Moreover, since I guess you have put $u=\frac{1+|a|}{1-|a|}$ and similarly for $v$ and $w$, the member is equal to $\frac 12\left(u^2+v^2+w^2\right)$. But $ u^2+v^2+w^2\ge 3$  does not follow from $u^3+v^3+w^3\ge 3$, but vise versa. A variant is that you have put $u=\frac{1+a}{1-a}$ and similarly for $v$ and $w$, but then I don’t see how did you come to the inequalities with moduli of variables $a$, $b$, and $c$, but not with variables.

> If you want to know more see this french website.More particulary the big message at the end where I use Karamata's inequality , rearrangement inequality , and other things.

Once at MSE I found an error in a solution in Chinese, so French didn’t stop me. :-)

You considered only the case $u\ge v\ge 1\ge w$, but don’t mention, why. If this is one of the hardest cases of  Rosenberg’s inequality, then it may be as hard as the initial inequality. If no, there may be no much reason to introduce a new inequality for an easy particular case. We can also consider cases separately, but for one of the them the approach may fail. Especially it concerns for cyclic inequalities.

You didn’t write why in this case $1> a, b> 0$ and $0> c> -1$.

I think it is bad to put $c<0$ but further dealing usually with $|c|$ (I think it is much better to put $c>0$ instead and deal with $-c$ sometimes). Moreover, I guess, you lost the modulo sometimes.

I’m proving inequalities for more than a quarter of a century, and my experience says that inaccuracy when dealing with them, especially with cumbersome ones, is a way to a hell. :-)

I have an impression that your calculations in the message mostly suffer from losing and reappearing signs or modules. Nevertheless, this may lead to critical errors (see below about conflicts). But to track the signs and to point each error in your arguments is less easy than to recalculate them. So I think it would be a good exercise for you which you can place in your answer to this question. Instead I give you general relevant advices how to reach a heaven proving inequalities, :-) partially illustrated by fragments of the  message.

Keep order and symmetry. Don’t write $\frac{(a+1)^3}{2(1-a)a}\Big(\frac 1{1-a}$, but $\frac{(b+1)^3}{2(b-1)b}\Big(\frac 1{b-1}$. Don’t relate $p_2$ with $c$ and $p_3$ with $b$. The Theorem 3 is applied to decreasing tuples, so we have to put variables in it in a correct order. (To achieve this order we may need to impose additional restrictions like $a\ge b$, which later may conflict with conditions like $b\ge a$ needed to prove that Condition 1.7 is satisfied).

Be careful multiplying both sides of an inequality by values which may be negative.

It is (much) more convenient to deal with non-negative variables than with real, with fractions than with radicals, and with polynomials than with fractions.

Do a weak check of obtained expressions sometimes, especially after multiplying brackets with many members. It can be done, for instance by counting the number (and orders) of obtained members or by giving to all variables equal values (often $1$), which usually should give a equality of the numbers obtained at the left hand size and the right hand size.

Sometimes a software is helpful for routine transformations.

After routine transformations formulate final expressions as simple as possible.

Use computer calculations, 2D and 3D graphs for an evidence whether an inequality needed for a proof is true.

If you came to an easy solution of an inequality in which masters were stick, be critical to it.

Good luck! It is indeed needed sometimes to choose a right way to prove an inequality.

Comment: Thanks for all your advice dear Alex .