# Solution to a hard inequality

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, proof-verification, contest-math

it’s related to this [If $a^3+b^3+c^3=3$ so $\frac{a^3}{a+b}+\frac{b^3}{b+c}+\frac{c^3}{c+a}\geq\frac{3}{2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2131374/if-a3b3c3-3-so-fraca3ab-fracb3bc-fracc3ca-geq-frac?noredirect=1&lq=1) :

My try  with $a\geq b \geq c$ :

We start with a substitution :
$x=\frac{a}{b}$$\quad$$y=\frac{b}{c}$$\quad$$z=\frac{c}{a}$
We get (from the original inequality) :
$$\frac{x^3}{x+1}+\frac{y}{y+1}+\frac{y^2}{z+1}\ge 1.5(3)^{\frac{-2}{3}}(x^3+1+z^3)^{\frac{2}{3}}$$
With the condition :
$$\frac{1}{x^3+1+\frac{1}{y^3}}+\frac{1}{y^3+1+\frac{1}{z^3}}+\frac{1}{z^3+1+\frac{1}{x^3}}=1$$
Wich is equivalent to :
$$xyz=1$$
So with the condition we get :
$$\frac{x^3}{x+1}+\frac{y}{y+1}+\frac{y^2}{\frac{1}{xy}+1}-1.5(3)^{\frac{-2}{3}}(x^3+1+\frac{1}{(xy)^3})^{\frac{2}{3}}\ge 0$$We intitulate this inequality$ (E)$

With the new condition $x\ge y \ge 1$ :
So we have :
$$(E)\ge\frac{x^3}{x+1}+\frac{1}{1+1}+\frac{x}{x+1} -1.5(3)^{\frac{-2}{3}}(x^3+1+\frac{1}{(1)^3})^{\frac{2}{3}}=f(x)\geq 0$$
Because we have :
$$\frac{x}{x+1}\leq \frac{y^2}{\frac{1}{xy}+1}$$
The study of the function $f(x)$ is omitted but a graphic could convince you .

Thanks for your advices .

Comment: what inequality want you to prove?

Comment: the inequality posted by Mr. Rozenberg?

Comment: @Dr.Sonnhard Graubner yes it's a provisoire to prove this .

Answer (score 0):

plugging $$a=\frac{x}{y},b=\frac{y}{z},c=\frac{z}{x}$$ in the equation $$a^3+b^3+c^3-3=0$$ we get
$$\left( {x}^{2}z+x{y}^{2}+{z}^{2}y \right)  \left( {z}^{2}{x}^{4}-{y}^
{2}z{x}^{3}+{y}^{4}{x}^{2}-y{z}^{3}{x}^{2}-{y}^{3}{z}^{2}x+{y}^{2}{z}^
{4} \right) 
=0$$
we have the equation
$$(x^2z)^2+(xy^2)^2+(z^2y)^2=x^3y^2z+y^3z^2x+z^3x^2y$$
remember that
$$X^2+Y^2+Z^2\geq XY+XZ+ZX$$

Comment: That does not answer the question I think .

Comment: i think so, have a look at the second factor!

Comment: Could you be more specific ?