# Proving a small inequality

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I am given that $a^3+b^3+c^3=3$ where a, b, c are positive numbers and I need to prove that
$$\frac {3(ab+bc+ac)+a^3c^2+b^3a^2+c^3b^2}{(a+b)(b+c)(a+c)}\ge \frac {3}{2}$$

At first it seems to me that the inequality might be wrong. I have tried using the Cauchy Schwarz , AM GM and some algebraic manipulations to reach the inequality but none of them helped me out.

Can somebody around  here help me to prove this small inequality. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be correct. If we take $a = b = c = 1$, then the l.h.s. of the inequality is $\frac{3}{8}$, which is smaller than $\frac{3}{2}$.

Comment: @Manthanein did you get the signs wrong by any chance? I mean $\ge$ instead of $\le$? Or $+$ instead of $-$ anywhere?

Comment: Well now I detected the flaw and have edited the question

Comment: How can an inequality be “small”? Is that a ploy to entice others to answer?

Comment: @Chase Ryan Taylor Well that was some sarcastic word in the question because the inequality nowhere seems to be "small" for me. By the way did you try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{3ab+a^3c^2}{\prod\limits_{cyc}(a+b)}\geq\frac{3}{2}$$ or

$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{(a^3+b^3+c^3)ab+a^3c^2}{\prod\limits_{cyc}(a+b)}\geq\frac{3}{2}$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^4b+a^4c+a^3bc+a^3c^2}{\prod\limits_{cyc}(a+b)}\geq\frac{3}{2}$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^3(ab+ac+bc+c^2)}{\prod\limits_{cyc}(a+b)}\geq\frac{3}{2}$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^3(b+c)(c+a)}{\prod\limits_{cyc}(a+b)}\geq\frac{3}{2}$$or
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^3}{a+b}\geq\frac{3}{2}$$ and see here:

[If $a^3+b^3+c^3=3$ so $\frac{a^3}{a+b}+\frac{b^3}{b+c}+\frac{c^3}{c+a}\geq\frac{3}{2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2131374)

Comment: Yep,  I got that. I have added the extension of Sonnhard Graubner answer to your question

Comment: But the answer of Sonnhard is total wrong.

Comment: Yeah I got that.